# Pasar datos de fila seleccionada a ventana modal usando datatables

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, datatables, modalform

hola verán tengo unos datos los cuales los muestro usando datatables.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que necesito es que al dar click en el boton de "retornar", se abra la ventana modal con cada uno de los datos de esa fila.

Este es mi código que estoy usando actualmente, investigue un poco en como agregar un botón en la ultima columna para que me permita abrir el modal y lo conseguí, pero para pasar los datos al modal si no encuentro como.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {                     
        var table = $('#tbl-contact').DataTable({
                "scrollX": true,
                "pagingType": "numbers",
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": "pagRetornos.php",                  
                order: [[1, 'desc']],
                columnDefs: [{
                    targets: "_all",
                    orderable: true,
                    render: createManageBtn, "data": null, "targets": [3],
                             }],




              language: {
                    "decimal": "",
                    "emptyTable": "No hay información",
                    "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Entradas",
                    "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Entradas",
                    "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
                    "infoPostFix": "",
                    "thousands": ",",
                    "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Entradas",
                    "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                    "processing": "Procesando...",
                    "search": "Buscar:",
                    "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
                    "paginate": {
                        "first": "Primero",
                        "last": "Ultimo",
                        "next": "Siguiente",
                        "previous": "Anterior"
                             }
                    },           




              
        });

        table.columns().every(function () {
            var table = this;
            $('input', this.header()).on('keyup change', function () {
                if (table.search() !== this.value) {
                       table.search(this.value).draw();
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>


</script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function createManageBtn() {
        return '<input type="submit" value= "Retornar" id="btneliminar" class="btn btn-success"  
 data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalRetornar">';
    }
   
</script>  
     <!-- Contenido -->         
<div class="datatable-container">
    
    <table name="tbl-contact"  style="text-align:center;" id="tbl-contact" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">   

        <thead>
            <tr>                  
                <th>DNI</th>                   
                <th>DESCRIPCIÓN</th>                   
                <th>CANTIDAD</th>
                <th>ACCIÓN</th>                                 
            </tr>
        </thead>
        
    </table>
</div>
  <!-- Fin Contenido --> 



     <!--------------------- MODAL RETORNAR STOCK ---------------->

<div class="modal fade" id="modalRetornar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
             <form method="POST" id="modal-retornar">
                <!-- <form method="POST" action="procesos/agregarStock.php"> -->
                <div class="modal-header">                      
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Devolución  de uniformes:</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">    
                    <table style="text-align:center; width:100%">
                    <tr>
                                      
                                          
                    <label for="encargado">Personal responsable - DNI:</label>
                    <br>  
                    <input type="text" id="encargado" name="txt-encargado" class="form-control">
                    <br>
                    <label for="description">Descripción:</label>
                    <br>  
                    <input type="text" id="description" name="txt-description" class="form-control">
                    <br>                         
                    <label for="campo-numerico">Cantidad a retornar:</label>
                    <input  style="text-align:center; width:15%" type="number" class="form-control" id="campo-numerico" name="cantidad"  min="1" pattern="^[0-9]+" onpaste="return false;" onDrop="return false;" autocomplete=off value="1" >
                    
                    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="txt-id" class="form-control" >
                        
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancelar">                     
                    <input type="submit" id="btn-agregar" class="btn btn-success" value="Devolver">                          
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi ventana modal, la cual tengo que, por ejemplo pasar el dato de la columda dni y el dato de la columna descripción, para luego ya poder hacer mis operaciones respectivas.

Y este es mi archivo pagRetornos.php:

```
<?php

    // DB table to use
     $table = 'tabla_pendientes';

      // Table's primary key
      $primaryKey = 'id_pendiente';


   $data = array(
      array( 'db' => 'dni', 'dt' => 0 ),  
      array( 'db' => 'descripcion',   'dt' => 1 ),  
      array( 'db' => 'cantidad','dt' => 2,),
        );

    // SQL server connection information
      $sql_details = array(
            'user' => 'root',
            'pass' => '',
             'db'   => 'kardex',
              'host' => 'localhost'
      );



 require( 'vendor/DataTables/server-side/scripts/ssp.class.php' );
 echo json_encode (SSP::simple ( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $data ));
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, acepto sugerencias.
Gracias.